# Is it possible to iterate through unique children with different values in Firebase Database?

Tags: android, loops, firebase-realtime-database

please take a moment to look at this Firebase database [Photo Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpeIE.png)

If **XRA** & **YRa** are both strings in an ArrayList, is it possible to iterate through the nodes **XRA** & **YRa** to get the data inside them without having to type their path in the listener for Datachange, i.e. if I have 10 nodes like them and I want to get the data in each one without having to type each of them as a path in the listener directory.

Below code works for one node:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Drawings").child("Area 71").child("XRA").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            key = ds.getKey();
            Current_Version = ds.child("Current Version").getValue().toString();
            Previous_Version = ds.child("Previous Version").getValue().toString();
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage());
    }
});
```

Comment: If you show the code that works for just one node, maybe it would be easy to adapt to multiple items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` from `child("XRA")` and set `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` on `child("Area 71")`

Then run a nested loop.

Note :  The time complexity is `O(n^2)`

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
.child("Drawings").child("Area 71").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        for (DataSnapshot parentDS : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

            for (DataSnapshot ds : parentDS.getChildren()) {
                key = ds.getKey();
                Current_Version = ds.child("Current Version").getValue().toString();
                Previous_Version = ds.child("Previous Version").getValue().toString();
            }
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage());
    }
});
```

Comment: how can i do this with recyclerview?

Comment: @Handelika can you be more specific?

Comment: @shb I try to reach realtime database with recyclerview. but i could't make it. I asked in here but no one answered yet. more then 4 days i am trying to reach data. I reach data with listview but not with recyclerview. I don't know what is the problem. my db structure or code side.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58121192/how-can-i-fill-the-recylerview-with-firebase-realtime-database-data